# Swift3: Usar linterna dentro de una aplicación

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

estoy trabajando en un aplicación para iOS 10.1 de lector de QR en Xcode 8.1 con Swift3. El problema que tengo es cuando quiero incluir un botón con la función de encender la linterna dentro de la aplicación (Ya que cuando lanzo la aplicación, la linterna se bloquea desde el Centro de control).

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
@IBAction func botonLinterna(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    func toggleTorch(on: Bool) {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else { return }

        if device.hasTorch {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()

                if on == true {
                    device.torchMode = .on
                } else {
                    device.torchMode = .off
                }

                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print("Torch could not be used")
            }
        } else {
            print("Torch is not available")
        }
    }
}
```

No he podido dar con un código que me sirva, tampoco he podido desbloquear la opción de usar el flash desde el Centro de control.

¿Conocen alguna forma de hacerlo?
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compilé el código que propones y me parece que tienes un problema al llamar al método.

Agregué un botón común (no toggle) y compilé lo siguiente:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var boton: UIButton!
    public var on : Bool = false

    @IBAction func linternaOn(_ sender: AnyObject) {

            guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else { return }

            if device.hasTorch {
                do {
                    try device.lockForConfiguration()

                    if on {
                        device.torchMode = .off
                    } else {
                        device.torchMode = .on
                    }
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()
                } catch {
                    print("Torch could not be used")
                }
            } else {
                print("Torch is not available")
            }

            on = !on
    }
}
```

Funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Efectivamente funciona perfectamente @Maetschl